# How to step envs in parallel using one environment per worker?

Tags: ray

We have built a system consisting of Docker containers, each running Ray. One container takes on the role of head and the others as workers. 
Is there a way to run our custom env's steps in parallel, while one env per worker per container is running? The methods mentioned in Rays documentation (https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-env.html?highlight=remote_worker_envs#vectorized) aren't useful for us, because we want one env in each worker.

Answer (score 0):

One env per worker is the default setting. You can increase the number of workers by increasing `num_workers`.

There is also the `remote_worker_envs` setting, which will run envs in separate actors but the policy networks in one actor for inference. However this has higher communication overhead than just increasing `num_workers` and is not recommended.

Comment: We are using 3 workers, but the problem is the envs they run are not run in parallel, At one point in time only one step() function is running.
We used the `remote_worker_envs` setting, but that only works when there are multiple envs per worker, but we can't do that. [The exact error](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/rllib/env/base_env.py#L87)